# Detect last call of JQuery Plugin Constructor after multiple instantiation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a JQuery Plugin that users will be able to call multiple times depending on specific options and preferences.

I'm looking for a way to know when they make the last call, because I need to execute some code during the very last call.

For example, let's say the code is thus:

```
$('body').myPlugin(options_1);
$('body').myPlugin(options_2);
$('body').myPlugin(options_3);
```

Is there a way for me to determine how many times that my plugin constructor has been defined e.g. before my plugin code is run, or from the last plugin constructor?!

Just as an analogy, in JQuery there is the `.last()` method to get the last item in a set of matched elements. I'm trying to do the same thing, only this time with Javascript Constructors, so can run some code at the end of all the calls.

Comment: I don't think what you want can be achieved, because knowing if a specific call to your constructor is the last one would require predicting the future. Humans are not very good at this, and computers are even worse.

Comment: @Frederic I'm not trying to predict the future, I was just wondering if there was a way that Javascript or JQuery could determine the last constructor.

Comment: With a running counter, you can determine if a function is called for the first time (the counter will be `0`) or for the nth time (the counter will be `n - 1`), but you cannot determine if it is called for the *last* time without predicting the future (or maybe performing deep code analysis on the caller's module). You can, however, invoke another function from the caller after its last call to your constructor.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `You can, however, invoke another function from the caller after its last call to your constructor`...How would I go about doing this?!

Comment: Put the function call after `$('body').myPlugin(options_3);`, assuming that's actually the last call to your plugin.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh, is that what you meant?! That's pretty obvious. Unfortunately, that won't be a feasible option because I can't shift the burden of making another function call to the user if they use the plugin constructor more than once (too much hassle). I'm looking for another way to deal with my challege

Comment: Then can you elaborate on the operations you have to perform after the last call, as well as the reasons why you have to wait until then? There may be another solution to your problem.